# Can't remove scroll listener

Tags: reactjs

### LandingPage.js

I added scroll event listener when mounting

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollNavigation, true);
}
```

I remove it before unmounting

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollNavigation);
    console.log("unmountedLandingPage")
  }
```

The function

```
scrollNavigation = () => {
        console.log("called")
        const doc = document.documentElement;
        const top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
        if (top > 80) {
          document.getElementById('topnav').classList.add('nav-sticky');
        } else {
          document.getElementById('topnav').classList.remove('nav-sticky');
        }
      }
```

### The problem

When I go to another page, I see that 'unmontedLandingPage' was printed. However, when I scroll there, I still see 'called' being printed. Why my removeEventListener didn't work?

Comment: You need to pass `true` to `removeEventListener` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a listener is registered twice, one with capture and one without, remove each one separately. Removal of a capturing listener does not affect a non-capturing version of the same listener, and vice versa.

Source - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

So in your case, you are registering a capturing listener but trying to remove a non-capturing one. It won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass `true` to the removeEventListener call:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollNavigation, true);
    console.log("unmountedLandingPage")
  }
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener):

> While addEventListener() will let you add the same listener more than
> once for the same type if the options are different, the only option
> removeEventListener() checks is the capture/useCapture flag. Its value
> must match for removeEventListener() to match, but the other values
> don't.